# Modal appearing then disappearing on button click in SPFX webpart when deployed to SP site

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, rendering, spfx

I have two webparts. One webpart is almost identical to the other.
Webpart A has a button which a user can click on and it shows a modal.
Webpart B has a button which a user can click on, it loads the modal and half a second later it disappears. Webpart B works correctly when testing on workbench on SPO site, but shows the above behaviour when deployed to an actual SPO site as a .sppkg file.
I've checked the modals state and it is correctly toggling between true and false.

I'm using:
Edge Chromium,
SPO communications site with wide column type page (WebPart A works correctly on this)
Windows 10,
Node version v8.16.0,
build tools version 8.16.0

Here's the code which brings up the modal:

```
if(this.state.showModal !== true){
    return (
      
        <div className={styles.jobeval}>
          <div className={styles.container}>
           ... //here is a list of items that are successfully retrieved from an SPO list
            <div className={styles.row}>
              <div className={styles.column}>
                <DefaultButton
                  disabled={false}
                  checked={true}
                  text="New"
                  onClick={this._onNew} //this button sets the modal's is Open state to true
                />
              </div>
            </div>
       
        </div>
        );
      } else if(this.state.showModal == true) {
        return(
     
          <Modal

          titleAriaId={this._titleId}
          subtitleAriaId={this._subtitleId}
          isOpen={this.state.showModal}
          onDismiss={this._closeModal}
        closeButtonAriaLabel={"Close"}
        isBlocking={true}
        containerClassName={styles.modalBody}
          
        > 
Here's the modal content
          </Modal>

     
        );
```

WebPart A has identical code, but has different versions of @pnp/sp but I don't think that's anything to do with it.

Any ideas - as a reminder, it works on test workbench but not when deployed as a package.

Comment: I think the difference is production vs debug build. Try running your webpart localy in the workbench, but compiled for production (add --production switch to gulp). Maybe some name overlapping, or optimization. For example (shooting in the dark) you forgot to `import '@pnp/sp/lists'` - that may break the production build, but not debug.

Comment: you mean gulp serve --production --nobrowser? If so, there is no change on workbench, it still works fine.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. In this case I don't now - if you share minimum self-sufficient sample to reproduce could check..

Comment: I've just deployed the package on another tenant and it's working fine. So local and site based workbench are fine and so is one tenant, but one particular tenant is not. It's a broad one and I understand that I'm not giving much away. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay :) Can it be a caching issue? I'd try opening the "broken" tenant in incognito mode.

Comment: With the @pnp/sp I'm getting back 404 errors, because I think, the address is https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/SitePages/_api/web/currentuser 
Should the sitePages be in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was unexplainable. I've looked everywhere and have finally decided it was something to with @pnp/sp not loading properly. I've changed the mounting code for @pnp and it works on more tenants now than it did, but it STILL doesn't work on a particular tenant.